# How to cancel delay in telnet connection?

Tags: telnet

I am using `telnet` on my Linux machine to connect to the PCU2 Service Terminal of a Flexi Base Station Controller.

There was some sort of problem with it, so my telnet connections were refused multiple times. Now it is OK but my telnet connection is refused.  I am given a message about a delay being applied.

linux version - Fedora release 15 (Lovelock)

```
[root@localhost ~]# telnet  180.144.58.109
Trying 180.144.58.109...
Connected to 180.144.58.109.
Escape character is '^]'.
/***DELAY APPLIED.PLEASE WAIT UNTIL <12.54>***/
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

How can I cancel this delay?

Comment: crossposted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436204/how-to-cancel-delay-in-telnet-connection

Comment: also, this has nowhere near enough information.  obvious answer is to contact the administrator of the remote host - have you tried that?

Comment: This probably has something to do with whatever it is that's listening on the remote device, not with `telnet` locally.

Comment: The remote device is not so happy with refused telnet connections and is limiting  them as a security measure. I advise not trowing out your common sense out of the window when dealing with technical issues.

Comment: FYI - the StackOverflow post has been put on hold in preference to this U&L one.

Comment: problem was in remote device. It got resolved by resting the remote device. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a telnet connection, anything after the line

```
Escape character is '^]'.
```

comes from the remote end. So it is the PCU2 Service Terminal of your Flexi Base Station Controller that is enforcing the delay.

So unless you have some other way of accessing your Service Terminal (i.e. not a telnet connection), then your only option is to wait. Making new attempts while the delay is still in effect may cause the delay timer to start over, so don't make new connection attempts until the specified time.

The delay is intended to make any attempts to bruteforce the password by automated guessing take too long to be useful.

(As the original poster commented, resetting the remote device got rid of the delay.)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to follow the instructions and:

> WAIT UNTIL <12.54>

You might also consider upgrading your [Fedora 15 system](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/15) that went end-of-life over 5 years ago.